# Powershell - Using a variable inside a variable

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to leverage Powershell with Azure CLI commands to create variables in an Azure DevOps variable group.

This is typically done using this command:

```bash
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id "variablegroupid" --name "nameofthevariabletoadd" --value "valueforthevariable"
```

Since this command is run in a powershell task in my AzureDevOps pipeline, the value comes from a previous step in the pipeline
In short lets assume that the name of the variable (coming from the previous step) is ***vmStorageAccountName*** then the following command works perfectly:

```bash
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id "variablegroupid" --name "nameofthevariabletoadd" --value $(StepsOutputs.vmStorageAccountName)
```

StepsOutputs being the name of the previouspipeline step.
However since I am getting multiple outputs from the previous step I don't want to manually modify the value name multiple times.
So I have a list of 3 outputs, for example:

```
$outputs = 'vmstorageAccountname', 'VnetName', 'Rgname'
```

I tried the following classic loop:

```bash
foreach ($output in $outputs) {
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id "variablegroupid" --name "nameofthevariabletoadd" --value "$("StepsOutputs.$output")"
```

But when doing that it takes *StepsOutputs.vmstorageAccountname* string (or any of the other outputs) as the value for the variable to be created in the variable group. When what I was expecting was to get the vmstorageaccountname itself as we do when not using the loop.
So I guess there is something wrong in the way I am filling the value argument in the command, using a variable inside a variable. I have trying many ways of writing the value arugment but none of them worked. Again if I am not using a loop and the $output variable, this works fine.
To summarize, what I would like is to first have `StepsOutputs.$output` translated to something like `StepOutputs.vmstorageaccountname` and then the value should be filled using `$(StepOutputs.vmstorageaccountname)`

I hope that is clear.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I’m prepared to be corrected by someone more familiar with Azure DevOps, so take this with a pinch of salt, but I *think* ```$(StepsOutputs.vmStorageAccountName)``` is substituted by the platform before your Powershell command runs - Powershell knows nothing about step outputs. If you want to inject all 3 variables into an array you’ll need to do something like ```$outputs = @(“ $(StepOutputs.FirstVariable)”, “$(StepOutputs.SecondVariable)”, “$(StepOutputs.ThirdVariable”)```, noting that ```$``` *doesn’t* need to be escaped as it’s search-and-replaced by *Azure DevOps*, not Powershell.

Comment: See **Set a job-scoped variable from a script** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) and **Understand variable syntax** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax) including “macro syntax” expressions in the form ```$(var)```

Comment: Thank you @mclayton. It did the job. I actually had to replace the double quotes by single quotes instead '$(StepOutputs.FirstVariable)' so it will not expand the variable before it is passed to the Azure Cli command and used by the --value argument.

Comment: @user2154222 - fab. Feel free to to post that as an answer (together with the actual code if you like) and you’ll be able to mark it as accept it in a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

Glad that @user2154222 for solved the issue. Thank you @mclayton for your suggestions that helped to fix the issue. Posting this on behalf of your discussion so that it will be beneficial for other community members.

Using single quotes fix your issue

```bash
# with single quotes
# without using additional string while passing value
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id "variablegroupid" --name "nameofthevariabletoadd" --value '$($StepsOutputs.vmStorageAccountName)'
```

#### Adding some more information to fix the issue:

If you are adding some additional string in your pipeline **--value**, you have to keep (double quotes) **""**. or just pass the variable value.

```bash
# without quotes
# without using additional string while passing value
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id "variablegroupid" --name "nameofthevariabletoadd" --value $($StepsOutputs.vmStorageAccountName)
```

```bash
#using Double Quotes
# using additional string as TESTAPP-$($StepsOutputs.vmStorageAccountName)
az pipelines variable-group variable create --group-id "variablegroupid" --name "nameofthevariabletoadd" --value "TESTAPP-$($StepsOutputs.vmStorageAccountName)"
```